Descending Sort with underscore in string
I'm trying to perform a descending sort on a column that contains an underscore within the string. This is my descending sort method.
protected void validateDescendingOrder(Integer column) {
    // create a column list
    List<String> columnList = getColumnList(column);

    // create a new list and sort
    List<String> sortedcolumnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortedcolumnList.addAll(columnList);
    Collections.sort(sortedcolumnList, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.contains("_") && o2.contains("_")) {
            return compare(o1.substring(1), o2.substring(1));
        }

        if (o1.contains("_")) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o2.contains("_")) {
            return -1;
        }

        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});

// sort the list using the custom comparator
Collections.sort(sortedcolumnList, Collections.reverseOrder(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
//sortedcolumnList.sort(customComparator);
System.out.println(sortedcolumnList);
System.out.println(columnList);
    
// compare the original list order with the sorted list to make sure they match
assertEquals(sortedcolumnList, columnList);

I'm expecting my sort to return
Test_jenn, Test_Community, TestRelease, TestCom1, test1, but instead it's returning
TestRelease, TestCom1, Test_jenn, Test_Community, test1

What exactly is your intended order when both strings contain "_"? The way you have it, you're comparing the strings from the 2nd letter onwards. This looks suspicious. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Also, I don't see any attempt to make it descending. The way you have it, it's an ascending sort as that's the default. And do you want it to be case-insensitive? Then you have to specify it.

please post a [mre] - posted code is not returning anything -- and also post correct examples - I do not believe that sortedcolumnList has test1 at the end

as mentioned by k314159, if (o1.contains"_") return 1; means that anything containing an underscore is greater then something without an underscore (and greater is sorted to the end, not to the start as you are expecting. || o1.compareTo(o2) will also not sort in descending order. || running posted code, with given strings, ends with sortedcolumnList = [TestCom1, TestRelease, test1, Test_Community, Test_jenn], not what was posted

You would benefit from running this code with a debugger. A debugger will allow you to set a breakpoint, and run the code one-line-at-a-time while monitoring the value of variables. When does the code do something contrary to your prediction? What were the values of variables at that time?

How do you want the code to compare a pair of String Objects if each has an _, but are different prior to the _? For example, how should Test_jenn and Register_jenn be compared? or Test_jenn and Quiz_Community?

@k314159, sorry about that, I failed to post the reverse sorting part of the code. I have edited the post to contain that.

@user85421, I failed to post the reverse sorting, but I have modified above to include where I am doing the sorting. The examples that I have given is my actual code that is giving me issues and not sorting correctly.

the last sort is basically overriding the previous one, that is, it is just sorting the entries (in the reverse order of CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) || maybe you want to Collections.sort(sortedcolumnList, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<String>() { ... with the previous Comparator ... or just add .reversed() after the Comparator (Collections.sort(sortedcolumnList, new Comparator<String>() { ... }.reversed());)

( in other words, reversedOrder() does not reverse the actual order, it reverses the comparator given as parameter, and then sort() starts a new sorting, (almost) ignoring the actual order of the elements )

(( another possibility to reverse a comparator is to swap the arguments (o1 <-> o2) )) -- also consider String.compareToIgnoreCase()

The problem
Collections.sort() is being called twice, and since calling Collections.sort() does re-sort the list, the previous sort is (almost)¹ ignored.
The posted code is basically:
Collections.sort(list, comparator1);
Collections.sort(list, comparator2);

so the resulting order is the one given by comparator2 - reverseOrder(CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).
The sorting of compartor1 - the anonymous class using underscores - is ignored!
That is, doing something like:
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder(comparator3));

does not reverse the previous order of the list; it does sort using the given comparator3 in reverse order. In posted code the Comparator being reversed is String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, so the list ends up sorted in descending case-insensitive order of the strings.
Solutions
Remove the second sort
Collections.sort(sortedcolumnList, Collections.reverseOrder(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));`

Alternatives to reverse the anonymous Comparator:

use Collections#reverseOrder

Collections.reverseOrder( new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.contains("_") && o2.contains("_")) {
            return compare(o21.substring(1), o2.substring(1));
        }

        if (o2.contains("_")) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o1.contains("_")) {
            return -1;
        }

        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
} )


just swap the arguments of compare
caution: do not swap the arguments of the recursive call!

new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.contains("_") && o2.contains("_")) {
            return compare(o21.substring(1), o2.substring(1));
        }

        if (o2.contains("_")) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o1.contains("_")) {
            return -1;
        }

        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
}


or invert the result
caution: do not invert the result of the recursive call!

new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.contains("_") && o2.contains("_")) {
            return compare(o1.substring(1), o2.substring(1));
        }

        if (o1.contains("_")) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o2.contains("_")) {
            return 1;
        }

        return - o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}

Notes

Case Insensitive
To obtain a case insensitive ordering, use compareToIgnoreCase() instead of compareTo().

Recursive Call
I am not sure what is the intention of the recursive call of compare. For me it seems to be an expensive and error-prone way for ignoring everything before the underscores of both strings. The compare method can eventually be called to compare each element with each other element, that is, it can be called very often, a non-recursive solution would be more indicated. Suggestion: instead of contains use indexOf() to search the underscores and substring() to ignore everything up to that index.


as I wrote, not sure what the exact requirement are.

1 - Collections#sort "is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort." (javadoc)
